# Spinner de Bootstrap desde un li

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#FirstSlide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#FirstSlide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#FirstSlide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

> cuando el li se encuentre activo deberá cargar un spinner, comienza desde el primer li, activo y la animación es desde que se comienza el count del slide hasta que termina y pasa hasta el ultimo li. para los estilos de bootstrap es el siguiente

```
<div class="spinner-border m-5" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only"></span>
</div>
```

> adjunto la imagen como se deberia ver este es el que tengo, es una fuente de font-awesome (circle)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que necesitas es que esos indicadores del carousel se conviertan en spinners al estar activos?

Comment: si efectivamente, en ejemplo la animación claramente carga desde los keyframes y haría falta agregarle los steps para que este se pueda animar ya que estan estaticos no mas desde un from y to, "Ojo respondido el ultimo comentario". saludos

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te propongo es que añadas las propiedades CSS que trae Bootstrap para su componente Spinner, que básicamente son un `border` y una animación controlada con `@keyframes`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinner-border {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinner-border {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.spinner-border {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem; /* Estos tamaños los quité porque los controlas con los indicadores del carousel */
  height: 2rem; /* Igual este */
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  border: 0.25em solid currentColor;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
}
```

Lo siguiente es controlar la apariencia de tus indicadores de carousel, por defecto tienen una forma rectangular, aplanada. Tu necesitas círculos, basta con aplicar las siguientes propiedades:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Ya para finalizar, solo debes juntar las piezas, aplica las propiedades necesarias del spinner en las clases `.carousel-indicators .active`

Revisa los comentarios que dejé en el código.

```css
/* Hace que las imagenes ocupen todo el ancho del contenedor de forma responsiva, opcional pero necesario */
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* No uses la regla !important, solo las pongo aqui porque no tengo acceso al orden de tu CSS */
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 10px!important;
  height: 10px!important;
  border-radius: 50%!important; /* Creo indicadores circulares */
}

/* Aquí ocurre todo lo que necesitas */
.carousel-indicators .active {
  margin-top: 0.4em; /* Evita que tu spinner se posicione por encima del nivel de los demás indicadores de carousel */
  border: 0.25em solid currentColor;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  /* Estas animaciones controladas por @keyframes son de Bootstrap */
  -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  color: red; /* Color opcional, claramente */
}


/*Ignora esta clase es solo para el snippet */
.contenedor {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="contenedor">

  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100.png?text=1" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100.png?text=2" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100.png?text=3" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

PD: La forma en que apliques estos cambios CSS, los dejo a tu consideración, no te recomiendo que toques el arhivo de Bootstrap, podrías crear otra hoja de estilos y llamarla después dentro de tu código, para que reemplace las propias de BS.

Comment: si, esta muy bien y claro el ejemplo, ahora solo para la animación necesito que tenga el efecto cuando carga esa animación depende del tiempo de duración de los slide ejemplo cada imagen dura 10000ms en ese transcurso se debe cargar la animación que esta sobre el li activo.

Comment: No te entendí, la animación no tiene ningún tiempo, la animación dura lo mismo que dura cada slide o elemento en pantalla hasta que pasa al siguiente, si tu lo controlas y dura 10s, eso mismo va a durar el spinner. Explícame por favor.

Comment: Me podrias compartir un ejemplo en  jsFile ? por favor