# Cambiar clase a elemento en jquery al hacer click

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

> en el siguiente enlace he creado un pen donde los elementos deben cambiar de forma dinámica, cuando este activo el elemento agregue la clase con los dos elementos que he creado en html, de forma practica se que puedo agregar una clase al hacerle click al elemento, ahora tendré que cambiar los elementos cuando cambie su clase active y agregarlos donde aparezca el active

https://codepen.io/dkinslert/pen/abdJmNQ

> El ejemplo lo he realizado en bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo haberte dado una respuesta a algo similar por acá: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/364208/83304 - Lo que necesitas en esta nueva pregunta es similar? No se entiende muy bien qué es lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola, ahora quiero que a el elemento que hace la animación de cargar cambie cuando tenga clase active o cuando se le haga click me sirvió la respuesta sin embargo aun todavía me falta jajaja